# python motor asyncio can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pymongo, python-asyncio, tornado-motor

I use asyncio to write to mongo, using `motor` library.

When I have few `bulk_writes`, it works with no problem.

However, when I have many write in the same time, I get an exception `RuntimeError: can't start new thread`.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/motor/metaprogramming.py", line 77, in method **unwrapped_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/motor/frameworks/asyncio/__init__.py", line 74 in run_on_executor 
_EXECUTOR, functools.partial(fn, *args, **kwargs))
File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2702, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_in_exector
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/features/thread.py", line 160, in submit
   self._adjust_thread_count()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/features/thread.py", line 181, in _adjust_thread_count
   t.start()
File "usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 847, in start
 _start_new_thread(self._bootsrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

I tried to change `maxPoolSize`, but it didn't work.

**Important facts:**

1. In my local computer, it works with no errors. However, in `Openshift` I have this problems.
2. In `Openshift` I run my code via gunicorn via `gunicorn app:app --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`
3. In `Openshift`, when I have only one `worker`, it works. But with 2+ worker I have this problem.
4. I don't open many connection of `AsyncIOMontorClient`, I have only two at a time.
5. With `pymongo` with almost the same code, I have no error, but there is no `asyncio` support in `pymongo`.
6. Without the part of `mongo`, my code works with no problems.

Comment: I presume you have checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63532917/python-cant-start-new-thread-multiprocessing, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283003/python-cant-start-new-thread-100-active-threads and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368906/python-exception-in-threading-cant-start-new-thread

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
There is a limit of 1024 threads per openshift pod.